# How is it possible to permanently mute a Mac?

Tags: mac, audio

At my school, the administrator seems to have completely muted our Macs. Students are not permitted to raise the volume, and when we try, a the volume symbol pops up with a line through it.

How did they do this?

Comment: I liked to find ways to circumvent computer security at my high school when I was younger too. Wanna know what it got me? A week of detention and a year of using a typewriter.

Comment: It's okay; I'm actually in a good situation with our tech admin. I find flaws for him to patch - but this one I'm not sure about. Once I know how they do it in System Prefs, I'll try it from the command line... Ideas how?

Comment: Try executing AppleScript using `osascript`. There you can use `set output volume` (documented in Standard Additions, I believe).

Comment: There can be a load of ways to do it...

Comment: @m0skit0 Explain, please.

Comment: I have no proper experience in OS X proper, but I know that you can do that in several ways in UNIX. I think best to look kine's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three ways off the top of my head:

1. If the Mac has an audio output method available besides the built-in speakers, the admin can change to an output method that doesn't actually output sound.
2. The admin could remove all audio-related KEXTs (in other words, the OS sound drivers)
3. I don't have personal experience with this, so this one might be wrong, but: An admin can use Apple's Server Admin Tools to restrict access to different preference panes, and i think *maybe* if they restrict the Sound preference pane it might prohibit volume changes. But i'm not positive, i'm not a system admin (and Apple's link to Lion's Server Admin Tools is not working at the moment, so i couldn't test)